# Using seq function and then sub-setting in R not giving desired results

Tags: r

While writing the following code in R:

```
seq1 <- seq(from = 0.05, to = 0.5, by = 0.05)
```

and then running the following code:

```
seq1 == 0.15
```

I get the following output:

```
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

When ideally I should be getting:

```
 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The funny thing is if I say:

```
seq1 == (0.1+0.05)
```

Then I get the desired output:

```
FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: This is due to floating point arithmetics. It is never safe to compare floating point values with `==`. Use `all.equal()`instead. More information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/4770166).

Comment: Or `dplyr::near()` to have it vectorized.

Comment: Please only use the `rstudio` tag if your question concerns the RStudio code editor. You wouldn't use a `pen-and-paper` tag when asking a question about grammar!